# How to get "multi word", "mono word" and empty strings all of them inside a TCL list? I get a list of "non uniform" curly braced formatted strings

Tags: string, list, tcl

I'm a complete newbie in TCL. Reading some manuals I've tried to modify some scripts I found here and there, and so far I've been managing my needs quite well... until today.

I'm facing a (probably) silly problem (for the PRO's), but not trivial for me, specially because I still don't have the whole grip of the concepts (strings, arrays, etc...)

My situation is this one:

I have a 3rd party application that returns strings when I ask for them. These strings can be multi word (space ' ' separated), just one word, or empty string.
These strings are unpredictable, I can't know the type of any of the asked strings, from among the 3 types described above.

A typical example of execution would be something like this:

```
list [format "%s" [lindex [some_function 0] 0] [format "%s" [lindex [some_function 1] 0] [format "%s" [lindex [some_function 2] 0] [format "%s" [lindex [some_function 3] 0]
```

Probably not optimal, but it returns this: (multi-word, empty, 1-word, multi-word)

```
{Hi you} {} finishing {this is string 3}
```

This format seems somewhat ok, but it is irregular enough to break my swift parser afterwards (when processing it, to separate the 4 strings into an array of 4 members)

Ideally I would like to have curled brackets in all my returned strings, no matter if multi-word, mono-word or empty string.
Somehow, "TCL is irregular" when dealing with mono-word strings... How could I achieve something like this ideal case?

```
{Hi you} {} {finishing} {this is string 3}
```

Curled brackets are there because it's the typical separator/operator TCL returns, but I would also be ok with something like this:

"Hi you" "" "finishing" "this is string 3"

How should I rewrite my original command for my 4 example strings?

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not parse tcl lists by other tools. It is error prone because tcl list can be in various format, especialy with escaping.

If you need to process tcl list by other tools, then you should convert it to some format which will be readable by this tool. For example, to `json` or something like this.

However, you can convert the list to simple formats like you described. For example:

```
set mylist {{Hi you} {} finishing {this is string 3}}
set out "{[join $mylist "} {"]}"
puts $out
```

This will give you:

```
{Hi you} {} {finishing} {this is string 3}
```

But you'll be in conflict with the `{}` symbols in the values.

Or:

```
set mylist {{Hi you} {} finishing {this is string 3}}
set out "\"[join $mylist "\" \""]\""
puts $out
```

This will give you:

```
"Hi you" "" "finishing" "this is string 3"
```

Now, you'll be in conflict with the `"` symbol in the values.

Thus, these solutions are not perfect.

Comment: I know a proper parser, and proper data structures, should be used, but right now, I just need to normalize the elements of my array in order to have a '{' and a '}' as delimiter for each of them. Just your first part of the solution did the trick perfectly. The devices I'm trying to connect are somehow low level so "adding some regularity" (and then some char escaping afterwards) will be more than enough for my needs. Thanks!

Comment: It's relatively easy to hack things with string processing like this… except when it isn't because of unbalanced braces. Then it gets really difficult because there's some horrible edge cases. That's why we recommend avoiding putting in extra braces with homebrew code; the built-in parsers and formatters may not do exactly what you want, but they're very well tested and they're fast.

Comment: Luckily the environment I'm dealing with is really home-brewish and non-critical, as regular text format is REALLY expected to be received. No human, but a process, will be creating such texts, so no braces are expected in the content delivered, and everything should be safe. Thin but safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc quote_words {mylist} {
    join [lmap elem $mylist {format {"%s"} [string map {{"} {\"}} $elem]}]
}
```

Then

```
quote_words [list foo "" bar {a string "with quotes"}]
```

gives you

```
"foo" "" "bar" "a string \"with quotes\""
```